Clearing React Object State?
I have a simple form that sets values into state via a object, for example:
const [customLineItem, setCustomLineItem] = useState({})

<Input label={"Name:"} onChange={e=>setCustomLineItem({...customLineItem, name: e})}/>

however, after i'm done doing what I need to do with the object, I want to clear its state out completely. I attempt to do this by the following:
const addCustomLineItem = async (payload) => {
   // do stuff

    setCustomLineItem({
        name: ""
    })

    console.log("CLI:")
    console.log(customLineItem)
}

but this isn't resetting the state, and that console log just returns the state sent into the function; neither is:
setCustomLineItems({})
What am I missing?
Thank you!

I believe it's the same, thank you Daniel!
